# How to get a Scrapy request to go to the last page of the website?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

I just need to make Scrapy request to request last page of the website.

I cant create a scrapy request to go to the last page. I have tried the code below.

```
last_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is None:
            yield scrapy.Request(last_page, callback=self.parse)
```

It is expected that the crawler goes straight to the last page, then from there I would do some manipulations

Comment: Can you please share the pagination div with the page numbers and next button.

Comment: next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class='page-numbers']/@href').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to go would be to inspect the source code to find the "Next" page link and use this function in parse:

```
current_page = #current_page_link
next_page = #scraping the link using a css selector
if next_page is None:
    yield response.follow(current_page, callback = self.manipulation)


def manipulation(self, response):
    #your code here
```